# Window.addEventListener For Scroll is Not Firing

Tags: javascript

I've added an event listener to wait for the user to scroll, there is a lodash debounce function to keep it from firing too often, and it affects the state of a nav widget on the page from inactive to active.

```
  function findActiveItemOnScroll() {
    const fromTop = window.pageYOffset;
    listLinks.forEach(listLink => {
      (...Code)
    });
      (...Code)
  }

  const debounceScrollEvent = debounce(findActiveItemOnScroll, 10);

  window.addEventListener('scroll', debounceScrollEvent);
```

However, it's just not firing! I've checked for any `overflow` or 100% `height` on the body/html. I've checked `window.pageYOffset` and it is scrolling properly. Are there any other selectors or JS functionality that can affect a scroll event that I'm missing?

Comment: @VirxEC the variable is assigned to a function... So it is being passed a function. Have you tried running a `console.log('check')` in the `findActiveItemOnScroll()` function just to see if you're 100% sure it's not firing?

Comment: @VirxEC WHAT in the world are you talking about. It can be a variable.... yikes

Comment: Hard to tell why it would not fire. Code should work assuming debounce is defined. I would expect it to be `_.debounce(findActiveItemOnScroll, 10)` if you are using lodash

Comment: does `window.addEventListener('scroll', findActiveItemOnScroll)` fire?

Comment: No, the event listener doesn't fire. I added a breakpoint to it in the browser inspector and I've added console.logs to both the listener and the function.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up resolving the issue. The problem was that the function was getting held up higher up in the chain and the event listener was never actually getting set in the first place, ergo, never getting fired.